# "Uma referência a um membro não estático deve ser relativa ao objeto específico" ao chamar método da própria classe c++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, opengl

Tenho uma classe em que, dentro de um método não estático, quero fazer uma chamada a outro também não estático. Porém, ao fazer isso, o Visual Studio já dá esse alerta: "Uma referência a um membro não estático deve ser relativa ao objeto específico".

A questão é que eu estou chamando o método da mesma classe, dentro dela mesma. No Java eu faço isso sem ter que declarar uma instância da própria classe dentro dela (isso seria uma redundância burra).

Como resolver isso?

Segue os meus métodos:

Método que é chamado:

```
//4- Cria os vértices e seu VBO e VAO. Define a cor a partir de um Uniform
void SceneManager::setupScene()
{



    GLuint VBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);


    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);



    glBindVertexArray(0); 


    GLint colorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "color");
    //assert(colorLoc > -1);
    glUseProgram(shader->Program);
    glUniform4f(colorLoc, 1.0f, 0.0, 0.2f, 1.0f);
```

Método que chama:

```
    void SceneManager::key_callback(GLFWwindow * window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
    {
        if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
        if (key >= 0 && key < 1024)
        {
            if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
                keys[key] = true;
            else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
                keys[key] = false;
        }

// O ERRO É SINALIZADO PELA IDE AQUI: QUANDO EU CHAMO O SETUPSCENE
        setupScene();
        switch (key)
        {
        case 65: //tecla A
        case 97: //tecla a
        vertices[0] = vertices[0]--;

            break;
        case 68: //tecla D
        case 100: //tecla d
            cout << "direita" << endl;
            break;
        case 83: //tecla S
        case 115: //tecla s
            cout << "baixo" << endl;
            break;
        case 87: //tecla W
        case 119: //tecla w
            cout << "cima" << endl;
        }


    }
```

Em um método anterior, dentro da mesma classe, o setupScene() já estava sendo chamado, sem erro algum.  Porque no outro método acusa esse erro?  ::

```
    *2 -INICIALIZA A JANELA GRÁFICA, INICIA O MÉTODO addShader() BUSCA OS DOIS SHADERS E SALVA NUMA VARIÁVEL,
    , INICIA O MÉTODO setupScene(), que cira o VBO e VAO dos vértices e define a cor via Uniform*/

void SceneManager::initializeGraphics()
    {
        // Init GLFW
        glfwInit();

        // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Hello Transform", nullptr, nullptr);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        // Set the required callback functions
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

        //Setando a callback de redimensionamento da janela
        glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, resize);

        // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

        // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
        glewInit();

        // Build and compile our shader program
        addShader("../shaders/transformations.vs", "../shaders/transformations.frag");

        //setup the scene -- LEMBRANDO QUE A DESCRIÇÃO DE UMA CENA PODE VIR DE ARQUIVO(S) DE 
        // CONFIGURAÇÃO
        setupScene();

        resized = true; //para entrar no setup da câmera na 1a vez

    }
```

Comment: Certeza que o método *SceneManager::key_callback* não está declarado como estático na definição da classe? A assinatura do callback da função *glfwSetKeyCallback* não deveria aceitar esse método, pois o primeiro parâmetro dele é a instância da classe (**\*this**) se não for estático, e ele difere da assinatura definida como parâmetro do *glfwSetKeyCallback*: `typedef void(* GLFWkeyfun) (GLFWwindow *, int, int, int, int)`

Comment: @Gomiero Tens razão. Na definição da classe o SceneManager::key_callback  é estático. Mas como eu posso fazer então para capturar o pressionamento de teclas e fazer com que isso dispare alterações no meu VAO? Eu não posso declarar o SetupScene como estático também né? Porque ele inicializa esse objeto VAO, e ele é um objeto de classe...

Comment: A ideia é que, ao pressionar determinadas teclas, transformações sejam aplicadas ao meu triângulo armazenado no VAO.

Comment: Tem uma função [*glfwSetWindowUserPointer*](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651) que permite você armazenar um ponteiro durante todo o ciclo de vida da janela (`GLFWwindow`). Não sei se a saída é boa, mas você pode armazenar o ponteiro da instância (*this*) com essa função logo após criar a janela e, dentro do *callback*, obter esse valor e fazer um *cast* para uma variável do tipo da classe e acessá-la de lá